# Boolean value always false

Tags: c++, boolean

I'm creating a book archival program, and one of the data members says if the book is read or not. However I can't get the program to write "Yes" to the screen, so I'm guessing it is never changed, even though I say 'Y' when asked if I have read the book. Can anyone see what I have done wrong?

```
cout << "\n\tEnter title of book: ";
cin >> title;
cout << "\tEnter author of book: ";
cin >> author;
cout << "\tEnter genre of book (1. Crime, 2. Sports, 3. Science, 4. Drama): ";
cin >> choice;
switch(choice)
{
    case 1: genre = crime;   break;
    case 2: genre = sports;  break;
    case 3: genre = science; break;
    case 4: genre = drama;   break;
}
cout << "\tEnter year of publication: ";
cin >> yearPublished;
cout << "\tHave you read the book? (Y/N): ";
cin >> ch;
if(toupper(ch) == 'Y')
{
    haveRead == true;
}
else
{
    haveRead == false;
}
```

Comment: The statement `haveRead == true;` isn't an assignment. Enable more warnings by the compiler, and it should warn you about it.

Comment: What happens if the user enters a choice not in the switch statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
haveRead == true
```

Is a comparison, not an assignment. Remove one = from both clauses

```
if(toupper(ch) == 'Y')
    haveRead = true;
else
    haveRead = false;
```

Comment: Or, it could be simplified to `haveRead = (toupper(ch) == 'Y');`

Comment: Thanks! My genres are in an enum, that's why they're not in quotes (though I suppose they could just be strings).

Answer (score 1):

The operator `==` is a comparison operator, used to compare things. Here you just want to assign, so you need the assignment operator that is `=`.